# Azure Mobile Client - Offline Sync Deleted Data

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Trying to better understand how the Mobile Sync Client works with deleted data from the DB.

So I've pulled a list of data objects from my Sync table like this:

```
public class AzureMobileService
{
    public MobileServiceClient Client { get; private set; }
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Debt> debtTable;

    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        if (Client != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Client = new MobileServiceClient("https://ajhmobile.azurewebsites.net");
        var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "ajhmobile.db");
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<Debt>();
        await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyLocalAndServerOperations);
        debtTable = Client.GetSyncTable<Debt>();
    }

    public async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            await debtTable.PullAsync(
                "all",
                this.debtTable.CreateQuery());
        }
        catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
        {
            // handle resolve
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Debt>> GetAllDebts()
    {
        await Initialize();
        await SyncAsync();
        return await debtTable.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

However, if I delete all the Debt data from the DB and a run a Sync Refresh, it's still returning the records, as if its not hitting the API and looking for fresh data.

Is there something I'm not doing correctly or just not understanding how the Sync table should be working?

I would think when I attempt to sync data, if I have records locally but the server no longer has them, it should return no results, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the records from the database completely, you will also have to purge the data from the table on the device before calling PullAsync() to fetch new records. Normally you would keep the records in place on the server but set the `deleted` column to 1. Then when the client pulls the updates it sees that those records have been marked deleted.

Comment: Hey Eric thanks for the answer. This makes sense regarding the soft delete. However if the records are purged completely, how can the client then know to purge locally?

Comment: You have to design your client app and your database maintenance to work together. So if you plan to be deleting records from the database, e.g. for records with deleted = 1 and updatedAt over 30 days old, the app should check when it launches if it has synched within the last 30 days. If not, it should purge and reload the database records from the server.